# Optimal duty cycle in Forward converter?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, duty-cycle

So as far as I understand the Forward topology:
The duty cycle set by the controller in CCM mode is constant assuming constant input voltage and constant output voltage. The duty cycle is independent on load, right? (Of course in DCM it is load dependent, but now continue with CCM)

So if I know the nominal input and ouput voltages and the transformers primary to secondary turns ratio, I can calculate the duty cycle it will operate with ( \$d=\frac{Vout}{Vin*n} \$, approximately of course, for being more precise I can calculate with the diode forward drop + other losses). Now the freely chosen parameter of these is the turns ratio, so by choosing its value, I can set the duty cycle of the operation.

The question is, what duty cycle should i go for? What are the main factors that I should take into account when choosing the duty cycle?
The topology I'm planning to design is with reset winding. Is it better to use most of the available time for reset? (I mean minimazing t_off-t_reset, limiting it only to safety margin to get proper reset)

Comment: _"The duty cycle is independent on load, right?"_ Pretty much. If you would add a term for the voltage drop accorging to Udrop=I(f*Lleakage+R)+Vfdiode you should be very close to reality, save for DCM mode like you say. Optimum duty cycle is a tradeoff between MOSFET voltage and current stress, output diode voltage and current stress and the amount of input voltage range.

Comment: Output diode voltage stress is clear (input voltage times n), MOSFET current stress is clear too (load current times n), but how does the output diode current stress (output current is a fixed value for a fixed output power) and MOSFET voltage stress come into consideration?
Or you mean MOSFET voltage stress affected by the ratio of the primary to reset winding, which affects maximal duty cycle?

Comment: Because if you design for a different duty cycle, you need to compensate by changing the transformer ratio. If you do that, everything will change. I forgot to mention reset winding diode stress, which usually sets your upper limit for duty cycle.